# excel 2013 vlookup formatting issue

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

the issue is quite irritating. i never encountered this issue with the old excel (2010). so here's the issue:

my vlookup does not work completely. first without doing anything to the file my vlookup will return some of the values but others will be returned as N/A. i've searched around and it looks like the issue was about cell formatting so i tried to format everything as Text and numbers or vice versa with mixed results.

lastly i've tried TRIM. it returned the old values that we're NA but messed up the values that we're being returned correctly. now again i've formatted it to TEXT and NUMBERS and still the issue persist. any good ideas on how to fix this?

thanks.

Comment: Start with posting a link to a redacted copy of your workbook and edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: In a [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) or [MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) function, `"abc" = "abc"` and `"1"="1"` but `"1"<>1`.

Comment: the trim and clean are your friends.  use them.  vlookup tries to match on characters you cannot see as well as the visible ones.